# Faster way to create a Complete graph?

Tags: c++, graph, time-complexity, graph-theory

So I have a list of names which I use to create a graph. Each name is a node on the graph and the edges are weighted with the minimum edit distance between the names. For my task, I have to create a weighted edge between each name. I have nested for loop to do this and it takes a long time for my program to build the graph. Is there a faster way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Do you really always need all edges? Maybe you could create them lazily, i.e. only compute the weight when it's needed the first time.

Comment: Well, after I have my full graph I am suppose to run Prim's MST algorithm on it from any arbitrary node...

Comment: As @user2079303 mentions below, creating the edges must be O(n^2) - there's no way to avoid that. However, perhaps your "minimum edit distance" function is performing badly...? Depending on what algorithm you're using, that could be exponential (naive recursive algorithm) or O(mn) on the lengths of the two strings, which can add up quickly if your names are long...

Answer (score 1):

There will be `O(n^2)` edges when you create one between all vertices (a complete graph). You can't have lesser complexity than that.